# Override getter with field works, but not vice-versa?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, the base class has four properties: a getter, a field, and a couple of methods that prints out the values of the other two.

In the subclasses, the base getter can be overridden by either another getter OR a field. However, the base field can only be overridden by other fields, not a getter.

I was a little surprised by this dichotomy.  Am I doing something wrong?

```js
class A {
  get foo() {
    return 'A.foo-as-getter';
  }
  bar = 'A.bar-as-field';
  go() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name, 'go', this.foo, this.bar);
    return this;
  }
  go2() {
    console.log('A.go2', this.foo, this.bar);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  foo = 'B.foo-as-field';
  get bar() {
    return 'B.bar-as-getter';
  }
  set bar(val) {}
  go2() {
    console.log('B.go2', this.foo, this.bar);
  }
}

class C extends A {
  get foo() {
    return 'C.foo-as-getter';
  }
  set foo(val) {}
  bar = 'C.bar-as-field';
  go2() {
    console.log('C.go2', this.foo, this.bar);
  }
}

new A().go().go2();
console.log('----');
new B().go().go2();
console.log('----');
new C().go().go2();
```

Comment: I see the same output for all 3 classes and for `go` and `go2`. Why do you think there's a difference in the way things are being overridden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation is easy: a getter is defined in a prototype, but a field in an object itself. So if the same field is in an object and its prototype, the prototype isn't used (JS doesn't look into it because the property is already found in the object):

```js
class A{
  get foo(){
    return 'bar';
  }
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(A.prototype, 'foo'));
```

To override a field with a prototype's getter you should delete this field from the base class' object in the constructor:

```js
class A{
  foo = 'bar'
}

class B{
  constructor(){
    delete this.foo;
  }
  get foo(){
    return 'baz';
  }
}

console.log(new B().foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong; this behavior is consistent with how JavaScript handles class inheritance and property overriding.

1. **Overriding Getters**: In JavaScript, getters are just special kinds of properties that run a function when accessed. When you override a getter in a subclass with another getter or a field, you're essentially replacing the property descriptor of that property in the subclass. This is why you can override a getter with either a field or another getter.
2. **Overriding Fields**: Fields are essentially properties initialized in the constructor. When you try to override a field with a getter, it doesn't work as expected because the field initialization in the constructor will overwrite the getter. This is why fields can only be effectively overridden by other fields.

The behavior you're observing is expected due to how getters and fields work in classes.

1. **Getters**: When you define a getter in a subclass, it overrides the getter in the base class. This is because getters are part of the object's prototype, and the subclass prototype chain will point to the base class prototype. So, when you access a property that has a getter, JavaScript will look up the prototype chain and use the getter from the subclass if it exists.
2. **Fields**: Fields are not part of the prototype; they are instance variables. When you create a new instance of a subclass, the field in the subclass will shadow the field in the base class. However, you can't override a field with a getter in the subclass because fields are initialized in the constructor, and they will shadow any getters with the same name.

Here's a breakdown of what happens in your code:

- `new A().go().go2();` will print "A.getter" and "A.field" because it's an instance of the base class.
- `new B().go().go2();` will print "B.getter" and "A.field" for `go()` and "B.getter" and "A.field" for `go2()`. The `getter` is overridden by a field in class `B`, and the `field` is not effectively overridden because it's a getter in `B`.
- `new C().go().go2();` will print "C.getter" and "C.field" for both `go()` and `go2()`. Both `getter` and `field` are effectively overridden in class `C`.

Some code to better explain this behavior

```js
class A {
  get getter() {
    return "A.getter";
  }
  field = "A.field";
  go() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name, "A.go()", this.getter, this.field);
    return this;
  }
  go2() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name, "A.go2()", this.getter, this.field);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  getter = "B.getter (factually field)";
  get field() {
    return "B.field (factually getter)";
  }
  go2() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name, "B.go2()", this.getter, this.field);
  }
}

class C extends A {
  get getter() {
    return "C.getter";
  }
  field = "C.field";
  go2() {
    console.log(this.constructor.name, "C.go2()", this.getter, this.field);
  }
}

new A().go().go2();
console.log("----");
new B().go().go2();
console.log("----");
new C().go().go2();
```

Result

```
"A" "A.go()" "A.getter" "A.field"
"A" "A.go2()" "A.getter" "A.field"
"----"
"B" "A.go()" "B.getter (factually field)" "A.field"
"B" "B.go2()" "B.getter (factually field)" "A.field"
"----"
"C" "A.go()" "C.getter" "C.field"
"C" "C.go2()" "C.getter" "C.field"
```

So, you're not doing anything wrong; this is just how JavaScript handles getters and fields in class inheritance.

Comment: It took me a bit to edit the original post and turn the code into a snippet that has output.  But, the local method `B.go2()` ends up with "A.field", the base classes, not the sub class.

Comment: This is also why you should define both getter and setter. Then you don't have inconsistency over whether it's a property or a normal field.

Comment: I tried the experiment with settings as well, thinking that might explain what I'm seeing.  But it had no effect.

Comment: I added setters as well in the subclasses.  No difference.

Comment: see the code I added

Comment: The output of your code does not match your answer.  You state '"B.getter" and "B.field" for go2().', but the result is actually 'B.getter' and 'A.field'.